# C# WebDriver Internet Explorer, How to execute in silent mode?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When using Internet Explorer Webdriver in C#, it  will output this message when the servers are started :

> Started InternetExplorerDriver (64 bit)
>
> 2.39.0.0
>
> Listening on port 37227

I found there is command-line switches *--silent* to suppresses diagnostic output when the server is started (https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver).

I didn't find how to start Internet Explorer driver with this command line.

My C# code

```
InternetExplorerOptions optionsIE = new InternetExplorerOptions();
optionsIE.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
IWebDriver WebDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(optionsIE);
```

I don't want to see these messages, how can I suppress them?

Thank's for your help.

Comment: why would you even want to suppress those? those messages are only for your benefit

Comment: Because I analyze (parse) console outputs. And this type of display complicates the parsing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be close to the code you want. Command line options for the "service" executables, like IEDriverServer.exe, are set through the corresponding service class.

```
// WARNING: Done from memory without benefit of an IDE.
// May not be entirely accurate, or even compile as written.
InternetExplorerDriverService service = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;

InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;

IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(service, options);
```

As a side note, and public service announcement, if you're setting the `IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings` option, [You're Doing It Wrong](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html).

Comment: But if I do not set IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings to true, I got exception "Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. (NoSuchDriver)"

Comment: Read the blog post linked to in the answer. Here, I'll [link to it again](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html). It explains why you get that error, why the bypass option exists, and why it's critically important to configure things so that you don't have to use it.

Comment: Jim, It's OK.
I check box labeled "Enable Protected Mode." for each zone and suppress `IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings` option in my C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
optionsIE.ForceCreateProcessApi = true;
optionsIE.BrowserCommandLineArguments = "--silent";
```

Comment: Helas, no success ! Always the message